# Getting HTML to work in a google scripts email system

Tags: html, google-apps-script, template-engine

So, I am trying to get an automatic system set up for my store where it notifies the relevant people that a bike needs building so that we don't forget about any as it does occasionally happen as a busy store.
I am pretty new to this as someone who usually just tries to self learn but I feel like I've hit a brick wall. I've largely been following a tutorial from spreadsheet.dev (specifically: "https://spreadsheet.dev/send-html-email-from-google-sheets") who has gotten me most of the way to where I need and I can get it to send an email with the notifications but, it doesn't go through with the HTML formatting.

Here is my code:

```
function sendEmail(){
  var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Emails").getRange("B2");
  var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue()
  var bikeData = getData();
  var body = getEmailText(bikeData);
  var htmlBody = getEmailHtml(bikeData);
    if (body !== ""){
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: emailAddress, 
        subject: "Automated Email: Bike Build Alerts", 
        body: body,
        htmlbody: htmlBody
      });
    }
}

function getEmailHtml(bikeData){
  var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Template.html");
  htmlTemplate.bikes = bikeData;
  var htmlBody = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
  htmlTemplate.data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  return htmlBody;
}

function getEmailText(bikeData){
  var text = "";
  bikeData.forEach(function(bikes) {
    text = text + bikes.bike + "\n" + bikes.due + "\n" + bikes.remaining + "\n-----------------------\n\n";
  });
  return text;
}

function getData(){
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Bikes to be built").getRange("Bikes").getValues();
  var bicycles = [];
  var whichDay = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Bikes to be built").getRange("N2");
    if (whichDay !== "Sunday"){
      values.forEach(function(row) {
        if (row[1] !== "#N/A"){
          if (row[4] < 4){
            if (row[3] == ""){
              var bikes = {};
              bikes.bike = row[1];
              bikes.due = row[2];
              bikes.remaining = row[4];
              bikes.status = row[5]
              bicycles.push(bikes);
              return bicycles;
            }    
          }
        }  
      })
    }
    else if (whichDay == "Sunday"){
      values.forEach(function(row) {
        if (row[1] !== "#N/A"){
          var bikes = {};
          bikes.bike = row[1];
          bikes.due = row[2];
          bikes.remaining = row[4];
          bikes.status = row[5]
          bicycles.push(bikes);
          return bicycles;
        }
      })
    }
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(bicycles));
}
```

and here is the HTML portion:

```
<div dir="ltr">
  <div>Notification: The following bikes are scheduled to be built soon;    
  </div>
    <div>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" dir="ltr" border="1" style="table-layout:fixed;font-size:10pt;font-family:Arial;width:0px;border-collapse:collapse;border:none">
            <colgroup>
                <col width="400">
                    <col width="305">
                        <col width="100">
                            <col width="100">
                                <col width="100">
                                    <col width="139">
            </colgroup>
            <tbody>
                <tr style="height:21px">
                    <td style="overflow:hidden;padding:2px 3px;vertical-align:bottom;background-color:rgb(31,150,244);color:rgb(245,236,62);text-align:center;border:1px solid rgb(204,204,204)">Bike</td>
                    <td style="overflow:hidden;padding:2px 3px;vertical-align:bottom;background-color:rgb(31,150,244);color:rgb(245,236,62);text-align:center;border:1px solid rgb(204,204,204)">Due date</td>
                    <td style="overflow:hidden;padding:2px 3px;vertical-align:bottom;background-color:rgb(31,150,244);color:rgb(245,236,62);text-align:center;border:1px solid rgb(204,204,204)">Days left</td>
                    <td style="overflow:hidden;padding:2px 3px;vertical-align:bottom;background-color:rgb(31,150,244);color:rgb(245,236,62);text-align:center;border:1px solid rgb(204,204,204)">Status</td>
                </tr>
                <? for(var i = 0; i < bikes.length; i++) { ?>
                <tr style="height:29px">
                    <td style="overflow:hidden;padding:2px 3px;text-align:center;border:1px solid rgb(204,204,204)"><?= bikes[i].bike ?></td>
                    <td style="overflow:hidden;padding:2px 3px;text-align:center;border:1px solid rgb(204,204,204)"><?= bikes[i].due ?></td>
                    <td style="overflow:hidden;padding:2px 3px;text-align:center;border:1px solid rgb(204,204,204)"><?= bikes[i].remaining ?></td>
                    <td style="overflow:hidden;padding:2px 3px;text-align:center;border:1px solid rgb(204,204,204)"><?= bikes[i].status ?></td>
                </tr>
                <? } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated as I feel that it will be invaluable to our store, especially in the coming Christmas season. While I am relatively new, if anyone is able to explain what is wrong as well as how to fix it, I will be doubly appreciative as I'm always wanting to learn.

Edit 31/10/2022:
For some reason the getEmailText function is now no longer working and feeds back as "cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined". That particular line is unchanged in my code though so I'm not sure why it's now not working. This largely seems to have happened after I changed my sendEmail function as my manager wished for it to send a slightly different email if it was a Sunday.

```
function sendEmail(){
  var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Emails").getRange("B2");
  var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue()
  var bikeData = getData();
  var body = getEmailText(bikeData);
  var htmlBody = getEmailHtml(bikeData);
  var whichDay = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Bikes to be built").getRange("N2");
    if (whichDay == "Sunday"){
      subject = "Automated Email Alerts: Sunday Roundup"
    }
    else{
      subject = "Automated Email Alerts: Bike Build Requests"
    }
    if (body !== ""){
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, body, {htmlBody});
    }
}
```

Comment: You provide a lot of code but I'm not sure if much of it is related to your question.  Is it only the HTML formatting of your email in `function sendEmail()`?

Comment: What do you mean that it "doesn't go through with the HTML formatting"? Does it not show the color? The font? the table?  You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure what could be causing the issue so I just provided everything. It is just the HTML formatting that's not working. It pulls data from the table I have and does all the properly but then won't format it. For some reason, the line htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent() flags as an error often but doesn't if you remove the brackets but doesn't work then. I believe it is something to do with the getEmailHtml function or the HTML itself as I replicated the exact code from the guide and it works fine but then in mine it doesn't. It just provides the raw data and no formatting

Comment: Can you show us a screen capture of what you want to achieve and what you get?  Because I'm still not following.  Note there is an unmatched `</tr>` at the end of your html.

Comment: Also there is a typo here:  `<?= bikes[i].due ?<>/td>` I think it should be `<?= bikes[i].due ?></td>`. Which is also affecting the last time since the brackets are not close properly.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistakes in the HTML code. Here are some screenshots showing what I'm after and what I get sent. I'm more confused now than ever as running the HTML separately from notebook is what provided the image of what I'm aiming for, so I'm guessing the issue is with the script. https://imgur.com/a/MUu6e64

Comment: For what I can see you are getting the part for the  `body = getEmailText(bikeData);` in the email, not the `htmlbody`. The structure doesn't look like the one in the Google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options) it should be something like:  `sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, {htmlbody})`

Comment: Thank you so much! That works! I don't really know why it didn't before as the guide I followed laid it out the way I had it and when I replicated their code and HTML it worked. But thank you so much @GiselleValladares you have made possible something I have been trying to implement at work for years!

Answer (score 2):

The answer comes courtesy of @GiselleValladares in the comments who noted a change in the structure for sendEmail would fix the issue along with some corrections to get rid of a few typos in the HTML. This is the corrected version of the sendEmail function:

```
function sendEmail(){
  var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Emails").getRange("B2");
  var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue()
  var bikeData = getData();
  var body = getEmailText(bikeData);
  var htmlBody = getEmailHtml(bikeData);
    if (body !== ""){
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, "Automated Email: Bike Build Alerts", body, {htmlBody});
    }
}
```